# I don't know how to stop a script

Tags: script, timeout

I copied and ran this scrip to stop my PC from going into the lock screen. Now I don't know how to stop it and having the "NumLOCK" reset every 6 seconds while working on excel is challenging:

```
Dim objResult

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
i = 0

Do While i = 0
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (6000)
Loop
```

I tried looking for the process in the task manager but I can't find it.

Comment: I suggest you just reboot.  Simplest way to kill a VBS script.

Comment: thank you, in the future you can look for the wscript.exe and end that process

Comment: I am more then aware of that.  The reason I suggested to reboot the system was for technical simplicity reasons.

Answer (score 0):

When simply double-clicked, or ran without specifying the script host, VBS will be executed by a process named "wscript.exe"

- Open Task Manager.
- Kill `wscript.exe` processes by right-clicking them and selecting "End Process".